# Can you start a Windows Forms Application on Xamarin for Mac?

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin

I want to be able to program in a windows form application on my Mac. I have visual studio on my desktop but I don't see that Xamarin has an open for it? It is the application where you can add check boxes and files menus.

Comment: You can open existing WinForms projects in VS for Mac, and even run and debug them. However, there is no visual designer and Mono's WinForms clone is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special Mac framework on Xamarin. But for using this, you need to change the whole UI-Layer of your app. And also you need Xcode for that. But the goal is, that your app feels and smells like a native Mac-App (and can be also sold in the Appstore)